# Python dict to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dict:

```
{6550: 610658, 6551: 610658, 6552: 610658, 6553: 610658}
```

I would like to convert this into a pandas dataframe with column headings 'Price' and 'Volume'. The desired dataframe would be as follows:

```
Price,Volume
6550,610658
6551,610658
6552,610658
6553,610658
```

I have tried the following:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

This results in:

```
,0
6550,610658
6551,610658
6552,610658
6553,610658
```

Im not sure why the first row is added. How would I create this dataframe without that first row being created. I also don't know how to add 'Price' and 'Volume' as the column headers.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you get the 0 as this a generated column name, to achieve the df structure you want, you need to reset the index as the first column has been used as the index, you then need to assign the desired column names:

```
In [52]:

d = {6550: 610658, 6551: 610658, 6552: 610658, 6553: 610658}
newdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
newdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
newdf.columns = ['Price','Volume']
newdf
Out[52]:
   Price  Volume
0   6552  610658
1   6553  610658
2   6550  610658
3   6551  610658
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler syntax for this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])
print df
>>   Price  Volume
  0   6552  610658
  1   6553  610658
  2   6550  610658
  3   6551  610658
```

notice though that the order on the dictionary is not preserved in the dataframe.

Comment: Your column names in the ctor don't match your output df

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is your 'd' variable. You must to define it like

```
d = {{'Price', 'x', 'y', 'z'}, {'Volume', 'x, 'y, 'z'}}
```